# Formula for calculating the difference between sums of digits in the same base for $(n-1)$ and $n$

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, decimal-expansion

I am looking for a formula to calculate the difference between the sums of the digits of $(n-1)$ and $n$ in a given base, denoted as $sb(n-1) - sb(n)$. Specifically, I want to find a formula that works for any positive integer $n$ and base $b$.

Is there a general formula that can directly calculate this difference? I would appreciate any insights or explanations regarding the derivation of such a formula.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how to calculate $sb(n)$? You can then subtract $sb(n-1)$ from it. While there is a closed form, it's not going to be "nice".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea
is to see how the digits change
when $1$ is added.

If the units digit
is not $b-1$,
there are no carries,
so the sum of the digits
increases by $1$,

If the last $k$ digits
are $b-1$
and the digits before
is not $b-1$,
then the last $k$ digits
change from $b-1$ to $0$
and the preceding digit
increases by $1$
so the digit sum
is reduced by
$k(b-1)-1$.
Note that if
$k=0$,
this reduces to the case above.

So,
if $kb(n)$
is the number of
trailing $b-1$'s,
then
$sb(n)
=sb(n-1)-(b-1)kb(n-1)+1
$.

The problem
is thus reduced to computing
$kb(n)$.

I have some ideas on this,
but the details are proving
annoying to figure out,
so I'll leave it at this
for now.
If I do figure them out,
I will add them
to this answer.